# "address not set" error in a Broker-Trigger configuration with Event Display

Tags: c#, knative, knative-eventing, cloudevents

Trying something really basic here to start things out.

Service "event-display-task1" is using the Go Event Display without issues.

My service "event-display-task2" is a simple image based on the example from github "eventing/event-display/csharp".

but I'm getting this error involving "Trigger: trigger-task2":

> address not set for &ObjectReference{Kind:Service,Namespace:knative-serving,Name:event-display-task2,UID:,APIVersion:serving.knative.dev/v1,ResourceVersion:,FieldPath:,}

[image]

Can you suggest me something? Thanks for you help.
Tom

```
apiVersion: eventing.knative.dev/v1
kind: Broker
metadata:
  name: broker-tasks
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
 config:
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   name: config-br-default-channel
   namespace: knative-eventing
   
---
apiVersion: eventing.knative.dev/v1
kind: Trigger
metadata:
  name: trigger-task1
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  broker: broker-tasks
  filter:
    attributes:
      type: task1
  subscriber:
    ref:
      apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
      kind: Service
      name: event-display-task1
---
apiVersion: eventing.knative.dev/v1
kind: Trigger
metadata:
  name: trigger-task2
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  broker: broker-tasks
  filter:
    attributes:
      type: task2
  subscriber:
    ref:
      apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
      kind: Service
      name: event-display-task2
---
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: event-display-task1
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/knative-releases/knative.dev/eventing/cmd/event_display
---
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: event-display-task2
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: serving-task
        image: acrnetasaas.azurecr.io/poc:0.0.27-test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: eventing.knative.dev/v1
kind: Broker
metadata:
  annotations:
    eventing.knative.dev/broker.class: MTChannelBasedBroker
  name: broker-tasks
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  config:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: config-br-default-channel
    namespace: knative-eventing
```

this change in the Broker made a difference for me.